# When does type inference become undecidable in typed lambda calculus?

Tags: complexity-theory, lambda-calculus, type-theory, type-inference

To begin with, if I understand correctly, in a simply typed lambda calculus, typing, type checking and type inference are always decidable. In the "full-fledged" polymorphic (terms depend on types) lambda calculus, type inference is undecidable. The same is true for types depending on terms. Now I have 3 questions:

1. What is the situation in the third corner of the lambda cube (calculus with operators over types, where types depend on types)? Is type inference decidable, and if not, to what extent do we need to weaken the expressiveness of type operators to ensure decidability? Or perhaps type inference is undecidable even for the weakest versions of this system?
2. Is it possible to identify some kind of "expressiveness boundary" for all three corners, separating system variants where type inference is completely decidable and, accordingly, undecidable ones? If yes, where is it located?
3. How does the computational complexity of type inference vary across systems? Is the "undecidability boundary" (if there is one) "sharp" (in terms of complexity) or does the complexity increase slowly (something like Blum's speedup theorem, where there's a certain complexity limit, but there may not be an algorithm that works exactly with that complexity)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally we prefer that you ask one question per post.